# Multi input Keras model shapes error: Matrix size-incompatible

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I'm trying to make a multi input model that takes image and text by reading them from a dataframe.
everything looked fine until training when i got the error listed under:

```
class MultiGen:
    def __init__(self, data_path, batch_size):
        self.data_path = data_path
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.df = pd.read_csv(data_path)
        self.train_df = self.df[:int(0.8 * len(self.df))]
        self.val_df = self.df[int(0.8 * len(self.df)):]
        self.tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=10000)
        self.vectorizer = None
        self.max_features = 10000
#         self.tokenizer.fit_on_texts(self.df['text'])

    def multi_input_generator(self, data_df):
        while True:
            for i in range(0, len(data_df), self.batch_size):
                batch_df = data_df[i:i+self.batch_size].reset_index(drop=True)
                images = []
                text = []
                for img_path in batch_df['image']:
                    img = load_img(img_path, target_size=(300, 300))
                    img = img_to_array(img) / 255.0
                    images.append(img)
                for txt_path in batch_df['text']:
                    txt = open(txt_path).read()
                    text.append(txt)
                    
                self.vectorizer = CountVectorizer(max_features=self.max_features)
                texts = self.vectorizer.fit_transform(text)
                texts = texts.toarray()
#                 texts = self.X.toarray()   
#                 texts = self.tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(text)
#                 texts = pad_sequences(texts, maxlen=150)
                labels = batch_df['label']
#                 labels = to_categorical(labels,num_classes=345)
                yield [np.array(images), np.array(texts)], np.array(labels)

    def train_generator(self):
        return self.multi_input_generator(self.train_df)
    
    def val_generator(self):
        return self.multi_input_generator(self.val_df)
    
    def length(self):
        return len(self.df)

    def train_length(self):
        return len(self.train_df)
    
    def val_length(self):
        return len(self.val_df)

    
    
batch_size = 32
# initialize the generator object
gen = MultiGen(data_path, batch_size=batch_size)

# get the generator
train_gen = gen.train_generator()
val_gen = gen.val_generator()



input_img = Input(shape=(300, 300, 3))
input_text = Input(shape=(gen.max_features,))

x = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu')(input_img)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(x)
# x = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu')(x)
# x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(x)
#
# x = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu')(x)
x = Flatten()(x)

y = Dense(64, activation='relu')(input_text)



z = keras.layers.concatenate([x, y],axis=-1)

output = Dense(337, activation='softmax')(z)

model = Model(inputs=[input_img, input_text], outputs=output)
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.summary()
# train the model
model.fit(train_gen, validation_data=val_gen, steps_per_epoch=gen.train_length()//batch_size, validation_steps=gen.val_length()//batch_size, epochs=10)
```

This is the error I get:
Node: 'model_1/dense_2/MatMul'
Matrix size-incompatible: In[0]: [32,229], In[1]: [10000,64]
[[{{node model_1/dense_2/MatMul}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_1955]

Comment: That would be helpful if you could provide a sample data file that you store in `data_path` in order to enable reproducing the problem .

Comment: it's a data frame with the path to the image files and corresponding text descriptions and labels. As for the files themselves, I can't share them sadly